# Create Spark Dataframe from SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, apache-spark, mysql-connector

I'm sure this is a simple SQLContext question, but I can't find any answer in the Spark docs or Stackoverflow

I want to create a Spark Dataframe from a SQL Query on MySQL

For example, I have a complicated MySQL query like

```
SELECT a.X,b.Y,c.Z FROM FOO as a JOIN BAR as b ON ... JOIN ZOT as c ON ... WHERE ...
```

and I want a Dataframe with Columns X,Y and Z

I figured out how to load entire tables into Spark, and I could load them all, and then do the joining and selection there.  However, that is very inefficient.  I just want to load the table generated by my SQL query.

Here is my current approximation of the code, that doesn't work.  Mysql-connector has an option "dbtable" that can be used to load a whole table.  I am hoping there is some way to specify a query

```
  val df = sqlContext.format("jdbc").
    option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/local_content").
    option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").
    option("useUnicode", "true").
    option("continueBatchOnError","true").
    option("useSSL", "false").
    option("user", "root").
    option("password", "").
    sql(
"""
select dl.DialogLineID, dlwim.Sequence, wi.WordRootID from Dialog as d
join DialogLine as dl on dl.DialogID=d.DialogID
join DialogLineWordInstanceMatch as dlwim o n dlwim.DialogLineID=dl.DialogLineID
join WordInstance as wi on wi.WordInstanceID=dlwim.WordInstanceID
join WordRoot as wr on wr.WordRootID=wi.WordRootID
where d.InSite=1 and dl.Active=1
limit 100
"""
    ).load()
```

Comment: Documentation about this (and more) can be found here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found this here [Bulk data migration through Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045392/bulk-data-migration-through-spark-sql)

The dbname parameter can be any query wrapped in parenthesis with an alias.  So in my case, I need to do this:

```
val query = """
  (select dl.DialogLineID, dlwim.Sequence, wi.WordRootID from Dialog as d
    join DialogLine as dl on dl.DialogID=d.DialogID
    join DialogLineWordInstanceMatch as dlwim on dlwim.DialogLineID=dl.DialogLineID
    join WordInstance as wi on wi.WordInstanceID=dlwim.WordInstanceID
    join WordRoot as wr on wr.WordRootID=wi.WordRootID
    where d.InSite=1 and dl.Active=1
    limit 100) foo
"""

val df = sqlContext.format("jdbc").
  option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/local_content").
  option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").
  option("useUnicode", "true").
  option("continueBatchOnError","true").
  option("useSSL", "false").
  option("user", "root").
  option("password", "").
  option("dbtable",query).
  load()
```

As expected, loading each table as its own Dataframe and joining them in Spark was very inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your `table` already registered in your [SQLContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext), you could simply use `sql` method.

```scala
val resultDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT a.X,b.Y,c.Z FROM FOO as a JOIN BAR as b ON ... JOIN ZOT as c ON ... WHERE ...")
```

Comment: By the way, this is not the gist of your question so I add this as a comment. If you are looking how to achieve previous steps (connect to mysql, etc...), you can check this post [Spark + MySQL example](https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/spark-sql-mysql-example-jdbc/)

Comment: Thanks.  I already found how to load an entire table into Spark.  However, my problem is that I have a complicated query joining many large tables, and selecting only a few columns.  I was hoping to create a single simple dataframe with only a the selected columns

Comment: How to register the table with SQLContext?

Answer (score 1):

to save the output of a query to a new dataframe, simple set the result equal to a variable:

```
val newDataFrame = spark.sql("SELECT a.X,b.Y,c.Z FROM FOO as a JOIN BAR as b ON ... JOIN ZOT as c ON ... WHERE ...")
```

and now `newDataFrame` is a dataframe with all the dataframe functionalities available to it.

Comment: Thanks, but  I need to join many tables in SQL and select only a few columns.  I don't want to load every table into Spark.  Can I create a SQL table to load via a query?  See the details I added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** just create a view in your database.

**Detail:**
I have a table t_city in my postgres database, on which I create a view:

```
create view v_city_3500 as
    select asciiname, country, population, elevation
    from t_city
    where elevation>3500
    and population>100000

select * from v_city_3500;

 asciiname | country | population | elevation
-----------+---------+------------+-----------
 Potosi    | BO      |     141251 |      3967
 Oruro     | BO      |     208684 |      3936
 La Paz    | BO      |     812799 |      3782
 Lhasa     | CN      |     118721 |      3651
 Puno      | PE      |     116552 |      3825
 Juliaca   | PE      |     245675 |      3834
```

In the spark-shell:

```
val sx= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

var props=new java.util.Properties()
props.setProperty("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver" )
val url="jdbc:postgresql://buya/dmn?user=dmn&password=dmn"

val city_df=sx.read.jdbc(url=url,table="t_city",props)
val city_3500_df=sx.read.jdbc(url=url,table="v_city_3500",props)
```

Result:

```
city_df.count()
Long = 145725

city_3500_df.count()
Long = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

### with MYSQL read/loading data something like below

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkMe Application").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
      Map("url" -> "jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/corbonJDBC?user=user&password=password",
        "dbtable" -> "TABLE_NAME")).load()
```

### write data to table as below

```
import java.util.Properties
    val prop = new Properties()
    prop.put("user", "<>")
    prop.put("password", "simple$123")
    val dfWriter = jdbcDF.write.mode("append")
    dfWriter.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/corbonJDBC?user=user&password=password", "tableName", prop)
```

to create dataframe from query do something like below

```
val finalModelDataDF = {
      val query = "select * from table_name"
      sqlContext.sql(query)
    };

    finalModelDataDF.show()
```