# A parquet file of a dataset having a String field containing leading zeroes returns that field without leading zeroes, if it is paritionned by it

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, parquet

I have a `Dataset` gathering informations about French cities,

```java
/**
* Obtenir un Dataset des communes.
* @param session Session Spark.
* @param anneeCOG Année du Code Officiel Géographique de référence.
* @param verifications Vérifications demandées.
* @return Dataset des communes.
* @throws TechniqueException si un incident survient.
*/
public Dataset<Row> rowCommunes(SparkSession session, int anneeCOG, Verification... verifications) throws TechniqueException {
  String nomStore = "communes_par_codeCommune";
  
  Dataset<Row> communes = loadFromStore(session, "{0}_{1,number,#0}", nomStore, anneeCOG, verifications);
  
  if (communes != null) {
     return communes;
  }

  LOGGER.info("Constitution du dataset des communes depuis pour le Code Officiel Géographique (COG) de l'année {}...", anneeCOG);
  
  Dataset<Row> c = loadAndRenameCommmunesCSV(session, anneeCOG, false, verifications);
  LOGGER.info("X01");
  c.printSchema();
  c.show(false);

  Dataset<Row> s = this.datasetSirenCommunaux.rowSirenCommunes(session, anneeCOG, TriSirenCommunaux.CODE_COMMUNE);
  LOGGER.info("X02");
  s.printSchema();
  s.show(false);

  Column condition1 = c.col("codeCommune").equalTo(s.col("codeCommune"));
  Column condition2 = c.col("codeCommuneParente").equalTo(s.col("codeCommune"));
  
  verifications("jonction communes et siren par codeCommune", c, null, s, condition1, verifications, SHOW_REJETS, COMPTAGES_ET_STATISTIQUES);
  Dataset<Row> join1 = c.join(s, condition1)
     .drop(s.col("codeCommune"))
     .drop(s.col("nomCommune"))
     .drop(s.col("codeRegion"))
     .drop(s.col("codeDepartement"));

  verifications("jonction communes et siren par codeCommune, join1", c, null, null, null, verifications);
  
  verifications("jonction communes et siren par codeCommuneParente", c, null, s, condition2, verifications, SHOW_REJETS, COMPTAGES_ET_STATISTIQUES);
  Dataset<Row> join2 = c.join(s, condition2)
     .drop(s.col("codeCommune"))
     .drop(s.col("nomCommune"))
     .drop(s.col("codeRegion"))
     .drop(s.col("codeDepartement"));

  verifications("jonction communes et siren par codeCommuneParente, join2", c, null, null, null, verifications);
  
  communes = join1.union(join2);
  LOGGER.info("X03");
  communes.printSchema();
  communes.show(false);
  
  // La strate communale doit concorder avec celle des comptes individuels des communes.
  communes = communes.withColumn("strateCommune", 
     when(s.col("populationTotale").between(0, 249), lit(1))       // communes de moins de 250 hab
     .when(s.col("populationTotale").between(250, 499), lit(2))     // communes de 250 à 500 hab
     .when(s.col("populationTotale").between(500, 1999), lit(3))    // communes de 500 à 2 000 hab
     .when(s.col("populationTotale").between(2000, 3499), lit(4))   // communes de 2 000 à 3 500 hab
     .when(s.col("populationTotale").between(3500, 4999), lit(5))   // communes de 3 500 à 5 000 hab
     .when(s.col("populationTotale").between(5000, 9999), lit(6))   // communes de 5 000 à 10 000 hab
     .when(s.col("populationTotale").between(10000, 19999), lit(7)) // communes de 10 000 à 20 000 hab
     .when(s.col("populationTotale").between(20000, 49999), lit(8)) // communes de 20 000 à 50 000 hab
     .when(s.col("populationTotale").between(50000, 99999), lit(9)) // communes de 50 000 à 100 000 hab
     .otherwise(lit(10)));                                          // communes de plus de 100 000 hab

  // Obtenir les contours des communes.
  // "(requête SQL) contours" est la forme de substitution pour Spark. cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376307/create-spark-dataframe-from-sql-query
  String format = "(select insee as codecommuneosm, nom as nomcommuneosm, surf_ha as surface2, st_x(st_centroid(geom)) as longitude, st_y(st_centroid(geom)) as latitude from communes_{0,number,#0}) contours";
  String sql = MessageFormat.format(format, anneeCOG);
  
  Dataset<Row> contours = sql(session, sql).load();
  contours = contours.withColumn("surface", col("surface2").cast(DoubleType)).drop(col("surface2"))
     .orderBy("codecommuneosm");
  
  Column conditionJoinContours = col("codeCommune").equalTo(col("codecommuneosm"));
  
  verifications("jonction communes et contours communaux OSM (centroïde, surface)", communes, null, contours, conditionJoinContours, verifications, SHOW_REJETS, COMPTAGES_ET_STATISTIQUES);
  communes = communes.join(contours, conditionJoinContours, "left_outer")
     .drop(col("codecommuneosm")).drop(col("nomcommuneosm"));
  verifications("jonction communes et contours communaux OSM (centroïde, surface)", communes, null, null, null, verifications);

  LOGGER.info("X04");
  communes.printSchema();
  communes.show(false);

  // Associer à chaque commune son code intercommunalité, si elle en a un (les communes-communautés peuvent ne pas en avoir).
  Dataset<Row> perimetres = this.datasetPerimetres.rowPerimetres(session, anneeCOG, EPCIPerimetreDataset.TriPerimetresEPCI.CODE_COMMUNE_MEMBRE).selectExpr("sirenCommuneMembre", "sirenGroupement as codeEPCI", "nomGroupement as nomEPCI");
  Column conditionJoinPerimetres = communes.col("sirenCommune").equalTo(perimetres.col("sirenCommuneMembre"));

  verifications("jonction communes et périmètres", communes, null, perimetres, conditionJoinPerimetres, verifications, SHOW_REJETS, COMPTAGES_ET_STATISTIQUES);
  communes = communes.join(perimetres, conditionJoinPerimetres, "left");

  LOGGER.info("X05");
  communes.printSchema();
  communes.show(false);

  // Y associer les départements.
  communes = this.datasetDepartements.withDepartement(session, "codeDepartementRetabli", communes, "codeDepartement", null, true, anneeCOG)
     .drop("codeRegionDepartement");

  LOGGER.info("X06");
  communes.printSchema();
  communes.show(false);

  //communes = communes.repartition(col("codeDepartement"));
  communes = communes.sortWithinPartitions(col("codeCommune"));
  communes = communes.persist(); // Important : améliore les performances.

  LOGGER.info("X07");
  communes.printSchema();
  communes.show(false);

  saveToStore(communes, new String[] {/*"codeDepartement"*/}, "{0}_{1,number,#0}", nomStore, anneeCOG);
  LOGGER.info("Le dataset des communes du Code Officiel Géographique de l'année {} est prêt et stocké.", anneeCOG);

  return communes;
}
```

and the field that is troubling me is the department one (`CodeDepartement`).

When the Dataset isn't partitioned by this String field codeDepartement: everything is working well

---

When that function runs, if I don't attempt to partition the dataset (the required statements for partitioning are commented here), everything goes fine:

The content displayed on the console is this one:

```
2022-01-18 08:47:50.995  INFO 25913 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.e.spark.dataset.cog.CogDataset         : X07
root
 |-- typeCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeRegion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CTCD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- arrondissement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- typeNomEtCharniere: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomMajuscules: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LIBELLE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCanton: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCommuneParente: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sirenCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- populationTotale: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- populationMunicipale: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- populationCompteApart: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- strateCommune: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- surface: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sirenCommuneMembre: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeEPCI: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomEPCI: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeDepartementRetabli: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCommuneChefLieuDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- typeNomEtCharniereDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomMajusculesDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- libelleDepartement: string (nullable = true)

+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------+----+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------+------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|typeCommune|codeCommune|codeRegion|codeDepartement|CTCD|arrondissement|typeNomEtCharniere|nomMajuscules            |nomCommune               |LIBELLE                  |codeCanton|codeCommuneParente|sirenCommune|populationTotale|populationMunicipale|populationCompteApart|strateCommune|longitude         |latitude          |surface|sirenCommuneMembre|codeEPCI |nomEPCI                                |codeDepartementRetabli|codeCommuneChefLieuDepartement|typeNomEtCharniereDepartement|nomMajusculesDepartement|nomDepartement         |libelleDepartement     |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------+----+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------+------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|COM        |02053      |32        |02             |02D |021           |0                 |VALLEES EN CHAMPAGNE     |Vallées en Champagne     |Vallées en Champagne     |0204      |null              |200056307   |576             |570                 |6                    |3            |3.616431731194736 |49.007989478704616|4168.0 |200056307         |200072031|CA de la Région de Château-Thierry     |02                    |02408                         |5                            |AISNE                   |Aisne                  |Aisne                  |
|COM        |02057      |32        |02             |02D |023           |0                 |BEAUREVOIR               |Beaurevoir               |Beaurevoir               |0201      |null              |210200564   |1433            |1415                |18                   |3            |3.330083095945232 |49.996641228776475|2180.0 |210200564         |240200493|CC du Pays du Vermandois               |02                    |02408                         |5                            |AISNE                   |Aisne                  |Aisne                  |
|COM        |02070      |32        |02             |02D |025           |0                 |BERNOT                   |Bernot                   |Bernot                   |0207      |null              |210200697   |461             |448                 |13                   |2            |3.4866867514904327|49.87884521170864 |1672.0 |210200697         |200071983|CC Thiérache Sambre et Oise            |02                    |02408                         |5                            |AISNE                   |Aisne                  |Aisne                  |
|COM        |02090      |32        |02             |02D |024           |0                 |BILLY SUR OURCQ          |Billy-sur-Ourcq          |Billy-sur-Ourcq          |0221      |null              |210200887   |220             |210                 |10                   |1            |3.2992043452730138|49.22146881666656 |1021.0 |210200887         |240200519|CC du Canton d'Oulchy le Château       |02                    |02408                         |5                            |AISNE                   |Aisne                  |Aisne                  |
|COM        |02291      |32        |02             |02D |023           |1                 |ESTREES                  |Estrées                  |Estrées                  |0201      |null              |210202743   |419             |411                 |8                    |2            |3.2807599426576335|49.97077968837569 |704.0  |210202743         |240200493|CC du Pays du Vermandois               |02                    |02408                         |5                            |AISNE                   |Aisne                  |Aisne                  |
|COM        |02527      |32        |02             |02D |024           |0                 |MORSAIN                  |Morsain                  |Morsain                  |0220      |null              |210205043   |464             |455                 |9                    |2            |3.1908402513250707|49.46152187457162 |1434.0 |210205043         |200071991|CC Retz en Valois                      |02                    |02408                         |5                            |AISNE                   |Aisne                  |Aisne                  |
|COM        |03098      |84        |03             |03D |031           |0                 |DESERTINES               |Désertines               |Désertines               |0310      |null              |210300984   |4519            |4432                |87                   |5            |2.627485866618113 |46.357035806459585|827.0  |210300984         |200071082|CA Montluçon Communauté                |03                    |03190                         |5                            |ALLIER                  |Allier                 |Allier                 |
|COM        |04138      |93        |04             |04D |044           |0                 |NIOZELLES                |Niozelles                |Niozelles                |0406      |null              |210401386   |284             |278                 |6                    |2            |5.847058475050684 |43.931981561717315|1061.0 |210401386         |240400440|CC Pays Forcalquier et Montagne de Lure|04                    |04070                         |4                            |ALPES DE HAUTE PROVENCE |Alpes-de-Haute-Provence|Alpes-de-Haute-Provence|
|COM        |05107      |93        |05             |05D |051           |0                 |PUY SAINT ANDRE          |Puy-Saint-André          |Puy-Saint-André          |0502      |null              |210501078   |480             |457                 |23                   |2            |6.566597158877383 |44.891314199898126|1530.0 |210501078         |240500439|CC du Briançonnais                     |05                    |05061                         |4                            |HAUTES ALPES            |Hautes-Alpes           |Hautes-Alpes           |
|COM        |05163      |93        |05             |05D |052           |2                 |SAUZE DU LAC             |Sauze-du-Lac             |Le Sauze-du-Lac          |0504      |null              |210501631   |149             |145                 |4                    |1            |6.323608116359499 |44.48601132516764 |1223.0 |210501631         |200067742|CC Serre-Ponçon                        |05                    |05061                         |4                            |HAUTES ALPES            |Hautes-Alpes           |Hautes-Alpes           |
|COM        |05176      |93        |05             |05D |052           |0                 |VALSERRES                |Valserres                |Valserres                |0514      |null              |210501763   |271             |267                 |4                    |2            |6.1382720630480465|44.48971119562803 |1123.0 |210501763         |200067320|CC Serre-Ponçon Val d'Avance           |05                    |05061                         |4                            |HAUTES ALPES            |Hautes-Alpes           |Hautes-Alpes           |
|COM        |07038      |84        |07             |07D |071           |0                 |BORNE                    |Borne                    |Borne                    |0713      |null              |210700381   |49              |49                  |0                    |1            |4.041460041609979 |44.61694459940681 |3199.0 |210700381         |200072007|CC de la Montagne d'Ardèche            |07                    |07186                         |5                            |ARDECHE                 |Ardèche                |Ardèche                |
|COM        |09120      |76        |09             |09D |093           |0                 |FABAS                    |Fabas                    |Fabas                    |0911      |null              |210901203   |356             |352                 |4                    |2            |1.1143034959106055|43.11978973617488 |2327.0 |210901203         |200067940|CC Couserans-Pyrénées                  |09                    |09122                         |5                            |ARIEGE                  |Ariège                 |Ariège                 |
|COM        |09231      |76        |09             |09D |093           |2                 |PORT                     |Port                     |Le Port                  |0903      |null              |210902318   |160             |159                 |1                    |1            |1.3862330079391603|42.83569938864616 |5016.0 |210902318         |200067940|CC Couserans-Pyrénées                  |09                    |09122                         |5                            |ARIEGE                  |Ariège                 |Ariège                 |
|COM        |09276      |76        |09             |09D |092           |0                 |SAINT VICTOR ROUZAUD     |Saint-Victor-Rouzaud     |Saint-Victor-Rouzaud     |0907      |null              |210902763   |232             |222                 |10                   |1            |1.5478697013903504|43.087886607776255|1270.0 |210902763         |200066231|CC des Portes d'Ariège Pyrénées        |09                    |09122                         |5                            |ARIEGE                  |Ariège                 |Ariège                 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------+----+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------+------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

The sub functions `saveToStore` are called, they are just doing this:

```java
protected boolean saveToStore(Dataset<Row> ds, String[] colonnesPartionnement, String format, Object... args) {
   return saveToStore(this.tempDir, isCacheUtilise(), ds, colonnesPartionnement, format, args);
}

public static boolean saveToStore(String tempDir, boolean useCache, Dataset<Row> ds, String[] colonnesPartionnement, String format, Object... args) {
   if (useCache && ds.isEmpty() == false) {
      String store = tempDir + "/" + MessageFormat.format(format, args);
      ds.write().partitionBy(colonnesPartionnement).parquet(store);
         
      LOGGER.info("Un dataset a été sauvegardé dans le fichier parquet {}.", store);
      return true;
   }
      
   if (useCache == false) {
      LOGGER.debug("Le cache est désactivé, le dataset n'a pas été sauvegardé dans un fichier parquet.");
   }
   else {
      LOGGER.warn("Le dataset est vide et n'a pas été sauvegardé dans un fichier parquet.");
   }
      
   return false;
}
```

A parquet file is created (a folder containing 200 files, like `part-00000-522c936f-7b72-4ed8-bab9-9d4acee6bc7c-c000.snappy.parquet`, not partitioned), and if I load the resulting parquet file with *Zeppelin*, I receive that content :

```scala
val communes = spark.read.parquet("/data/tmp/communes_par_codeCommune_2021")

communes.printSchema()
   
communes.select("codeDepartement").distinct()
  .orderBy("codeDepartement")
   .show(100)
```

```
root
 |-- typeCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeRegion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CTCD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- arrondissement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- typeNomEtCharniere: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomMajuscules: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LIBELLE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCanton: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCommuneParente: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sirenCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- populationTotale: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- populationMunicipale: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- populationCompteApart: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- strateCommune: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- surface: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sirenCommuneMembre: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeEPCI: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomEPCI: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeDepartementRetabli: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCommuneChefLieuDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- typeNomEtCharniereDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomMajusculesDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- libelleDepartement: string (nullable = true)

+---------------+
|codeDepartement|
+---------------+
|             01|
|             02|
|             03|
|             04|
|             05|
|             06|
|             07|
|             08|
|             09|
|             10|
|             11|
|             12|
|             13|
|             14|
|             15|
|             16|
|             17|
|             18|
|             19|
|             21|
|             22|
|             23|
|             24|
|             25|
|             26|
|             27|
|             28|
|             29|
|             2A|
|             2B|
|             30|
|             31|
|             32|
|             33|
|             34|
|             35|
|             36|
|             37|
|             38|
|             39|
|             40|
|             41|
|             42|
|             43|
|             44|
|             45|
|             46|
|             47|
|             48|
|             49|
|             50|
|             51|
|             52|
|             53|
|             54|
|             55|
|             56|
|             57|
|             58|
|             59|
|             60|
|             61|
|             62|
|             63|
|             64|
|             65|
|             66|
|             67|
|             68|
|             69|
|             70|
|             71|
|             72|
|             73|
|             74|
|             75|
|             76|
|             77|
|             78|
|             79|
|             80|
|             81|
|             82|
|             83|
|             84|
|             85|
|             86|
|             87|
|             88|
|             89|
|             90|
|             91|
|             92|
|             93|
|             94|
|             95|
|            971|
|            972|
|            973|
|            974|
+---------------+
only showing top 100 rows
```

The leading zeroes of the `codeDepartement` fields are here, and it's nofmal, this field is a string, proved by some `2A` and to `2B` that are code for *Corse* (North and South) department.

I notice that in the schema shown, `codeDepartment` is in fourth position.

When the dataset is partitioned with codeDepartement: leading zeroes are lost when the parquet file is loaded:

---

if I activate in my `CogDataset` source file the partitionning by codeDepartement of the Dataset, by uncommenting the lines:

```java
communes = communes.repartition(col("codeDepartement"));
[...]
saveToStore(communes, new String[] {"codeDepartement"}, "{0}_{1,number,#0}", nomStore, anneeCOG);
```

The content of the dump "X07" is the same, except that `codeDepartment` are ordered, and retain their leading zeroes, the parquet file has now subfolders like `codeDepartement=02`, (and `02` has its leading zero, so it's promising), but when I load that parquet file with *Zeppelin*, things are going wrong:

```
root
 |-- typeCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeRegion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CTCD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- arrondissement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- typeNomEtCharniere: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomMajuscules: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LIBELLE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCanton: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCommuneParente: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sirenCommune: string (nullable = true)
 |-- populationTotale: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- populationMunicipale: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- populationCompteApart: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- strateCommune: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- surface: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sirenCommuneMembre: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeEPCI: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomEPCI: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeDepartementRetabli: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeCommuneChefLieuDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- typeNomEtCharniereDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomMajusculesDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nomDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- libelleDepartement: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codeDepartement: string (nullable = true)

+---------------+
|codeDepartement|
+---------------+
|              1|
|             10|
|             11|
|             12|
|             13|
|             14|
|             15|
|             16|
|             17|
|             18|
|             19|
|              2|
|             21|
|             22|
|             23|
|             24|
|             25|
|             26|
|             27|
|             28|
|             29|
|             2A|
|             2B|
|              3|
|             30|
|             31|
|             32|
|             33|
|             34|
|             35|
|             36|
|             37|
|             38|
|             39|
|              4|
|             40|
|             41|
|             42|
|             43|
|             44|
|             45|
|             46|
|             47|
|             48|
|             49|
|              5|
|             50|
|             51|
|             52|
|             53|
|             54|
|             55|
|             56|
|             57|
|             58|
|             59|
|              6|
|             60|
|             61|
|             62|
|             63|
|             64|
|             65|
|             66|
|             67|
|             68|
|             69|
|              7|
|             70|
|             71|
|             72|
|             73|
|             74|
|             75|
|             76|
|             77|
|             78|
|             79|
|              8|
|             80|
|             81|
|             82|
|             83|
|             84|
|             85|
|             86|
|             87|
|             88|
|             89|
|              9|
|             90|
|             91|
|             92|
|             93|
|             94|
|             95|
|            971|
|            972|
|            973|
|            974|
+---------------+
only showing top 100 rows
```

Leading zeroes of `codeDepartement` are lost,
while `2A` and `2B` department codes are still here, showing that this field is still a `string`.

I notice that the `codeDepartment` given by *Parquet* is at the last position of the schema, as if it recreated that field itself (?).

Do you have an idea of what is affecting me?
It looks like I'm missing some options that I should set before storing to *Parquet* or reloading for it my content?

I'm using `Spark 3.2.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer.
The problem isn't the parquet file itself, but the fact that these statements:

```scala
val communes = spark.read.parquet("/data/tmp/communes_par_codeCommune_2021")
communes.printSchema()
```

even if they are displaying the good dataset schema, don't take this schema *really* into account, and try somewhat to infer it from data, while reading, as long as possible (?!),
therefore, considering my `codeDepartement` field as numeric until stumbling upon the values `2A` and `2B` forcing it to switch its field type to string.

I wonder why is parquet file loading working that way. And if my explanation is the good one.

But the correct way to ensure the schema of the parquet file is taken into account is to explicitly ask to extract it first from that parquet file, and then ask the load function to use it:

```scala
val parquetFile = "/data/tmp/communes_par_codeCommune_2021";
val schema = spark.read.parquet(parquetFile).schema;
val communes = spark.read.schema(schema).parquet(parquetFile);
```

and then the behavior of parquet file reading becomes normal:

```
+---------------+
|codeDepartement|
+---------------+
|             01|
|             02|
|             03|
|             04|
|             05|
|             06|
```

Maybe there's a simpler way to achieve that, if you know it, I am happy to learn it because this is a bit burdensome.